# Filter GET Request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Any suggestion on how to filter GET requests in nodeJS?

For example: Filter it with "username" and return only items which has a username of "admin"

```
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Welcome to roffys server')
    Todo.find({})
        .exec((err, todo) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error retrieving todos')
            } else {
                console.log('--------todo', todo);
                res.json(todo)
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: `Todo.find({ "username" : 'admin' });` for exact match or `Todo.find({ "username" : {$regex : ".*admin.*" }});` for string containing `admin`

Comment: And how can I do it manually? For examples if value of 'username' will change?